# Cannot read property map of unknown error

Tags: reactjs

I am developing a basic quiz app in react. I have a QuestionList component which sends question,options to another component Question as props. Inside the Question component while trying the following code

```
 <div>      
    {props.question}
  </div>
  <div>
    {props.options.map(option=>{return(
        <div> <button onClick={()=> submitAnswer(option.isCorrect)} >{option.option}</button> </div>)
    })}
  </div>
```

It is giving me an error that **Cannot read property map of unknown.**

But when I remove the second div, the question is rendered and after that if I paste the second div and save it the options are also rendered.

If I refresh the page in browser the error is getting repeated. Why is this weird behavior

**EDIT**
options is an array of objects

```
options:[
            {option:"Hyderabad",isCorrect:false},
            { option:"Delhi",isCorrect:true},    
        

]
```

**Parent component**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Question from "./Question"
const QuestionList=()=>{
const [questions,setQuestions]=useState([{}]);
useEffect(()=>{
    async function fetchQuestions(){
        const response=await fetch("http://localhost:7000/questions");
         const data=await response.json();
         setQuestions(data.questions);
         console.log(data.questions)
     }
fetchQuestions();
console.log(questions)
},[])// eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    const [currentQuestion,setCurrentQuestion]=useState(0);
    const [score,setScore]=useState(0);
    const [showScore,setShowScore]=useState(false);
   const handleOptionCorrect=(isCorrect)=>{
        if(isCorrect)
        {
            setScore(score+1)
        }
        const nextQuestion=currentQuestion+1;
        if(nextQuestion<questions.length){
            setCurrentQuestion(nextQuestion)
        }
        else{
            setShowScore(true)
        }
    }
    return(      
       <div>
            {showScore?(
                <div> 
                    Your score is {score} / {questions.length}
                </div>

            ):(
                <>
                <Question question={questions[currentQuestion].question} 
                options={questions[currentQuestion].options} 
                handleOptionCorrect={handleOptionCorrect}/>
                 
                 </>
            )}

        </div>
     );

}
export default QuestionList;
```

**Child Component**

```
    import React from 'react'
const Question=(props)=>{
    const submitAnswer=(isCorrect)=>{
        props.handleOptionCorrect(isCorrect)
    }// eslint-disable-next-line
    return(
        <>
        <div>          
        {props.question}
         <div>
        {props.options.map(option=>{return(
            <div> <button onClick={()=> submitAnswer(option.isCorrect)} >{option.option}</button> </div>)
        })}
        </div> 
        </div>
        
        </>
    );
}
export default Question
```

**Resolved**
Previously I was taking options directly from props. After looking at @Naren 's answer I got an idea how to take options array from props and edited my code accordingly and it worked.
Thank you!

Comment: What is the `options` props value from the parent component? Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for both the parent and child components so we may see what the value is from the initial render until the error occurs. It's likely the `options` value is initially undefined.

Comment: I think that you have done something wrong when passing in an options prop

Comment: sometimes I am getting proper output without any changes, sometimes getting this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

Your initial `questions` state is an array with an empty object but your are selecting the the first element and sending an undefined `options` value.

```
const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([{}]);
const [currentQuestion, setCurrentQuestion] = useState(0);

<Question
  question={questions[currentQuestion].question} 
  options={questions[currentQuestion].options} // <-- options is undefined
  handleOptionCorrect={handleOptionCorrect}
/>
```

Child - throws error because `props.options` is undefined.

```
{props.options.map(option=>{return(
  <div>
    <button onClick={()=> submitAnswer(option.isCorrect)}>
      {option.option}
    </button>
  </div>)
})}
```

## Solution

You should provide valid initial state that doesn't blow up your UI.

```
const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([{ options: [] }]); // <-- provide options array
const [currentQuestion, setCurrentQuestion] = useState(0);

<Question
  question={questions[currentQuestion].question} 
  options={questions[currentQuestion].options} // <-- options is defined
  handleOptionCorrect={handleOptionCorrect}
/>
```

## Suggestion

If `Question` component is rendered by other components then it's good to provide a fallback value in case you forget to always provide valid props.

```
const Question = ({ handleOptionCorrect, options = [], question })=>{
  const submitAnswer=(isCorrect)=>{
    handleOptionCorrect(isCorrect)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div>          
        {question}
      <div>
      {options.map(option=> (
        <div>
          <button onClick={()=> submitAnswer(option.isCorrect)} >
            {option.option}
          </button> 
        </div>)
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `QuestionList` receiving props`(question, options)` as undefined. Better to add fallbacks. Please add more code to your question to get better understanding.

```
const QuestionList = (props) => {
  const { question, options = [] } = props
 
  if (!question) return <span>loading question...</span>
  ....
}
```

Comment: I agree it is not a bad idea to have fallbacks. Another example will be to only do map of an array if it has length.